# Magento 2:- Updating table value

Tags: magento2, database, cart, crud

I want to update the value of `amount` column in custom database table where `customer_id` with value of `$total`.

```
$total = $array['amount'] - $arr['base_grand_total'];
$sortedData = $prepaidModel->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('amount')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',1);
foreach($sortedData as $sData)
{
    $sData->setData('amount',$total);
    $sData->save();
}
```

Not updating the value. But multiple records are adding in database table

Kindly guide.

Comment: What issue are you getting?

Comment: @DJDev Not updating the value. But multiple records are adding in database table

Comment: What is your `$prepaidModel` and also could you try to print this and let me know what you get.
`echo "<pre>"; print_r($sortedData->getData()); die;`

Comment: Are you able to get any existing data when printing above code?

Comment: @DJDev Yes. I'm getting result. I want to update it

Comment: Can you show me the 1 / 2 result array?

Comment: @DJDev Yes. Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 50000 ) ). Now i want to update amount

Comment: I provided code in comment. Please use that one.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299592/82771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code

```
$total = $array['amount'] - $arr['base_grand_total'];
$sortedData = $prepaidModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',1);
foreach($sortedData as $sData)
{
    $sData->setData('amount',$total);
    $sData->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of save multiple model instances at once.

**Try with below example**

```
class yourClassName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function __construct(
    ............
    \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
    ............
    ) {
    ............
    $this->transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
    ............
    }

    public function yourMethodName(){

        $total = $array['amount'] - $arr['base_grand_total'];
        $sortedData = $prepaidModel->getCollection()
                      ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',1);
        $transaction = $this->transactionFactory->create();
        if($sortedData->getSize()>0){
            foreach($sortedData as $sData){
                $sData->addData(['amount',$total]);
                $transaction->addObject($sData);
            }
            $transaction->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code Explanation**

At first we create a transaction instance from the transaction factory.

Then, in each iteration in the foreach loop we have an instance.

We set all the required fields(`amount`) and then we add the instance to the transaction.

The last step is to call the save() method of the transaction instance to save all the Table instances.

> Please note that, in case of errors, Magento2 performs a rollback:

```
// Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction::save()#L143:L148
if ($error) {
  $this->_rollbackTransaction();
  throw $error;
} else {
  $this->_commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Why again need to load model? It is not a good way to load again model.

Comment: @DJ Dev, Check updated answer